# Facing difficulty in installing unzip tool in Mac OS X using puppet script

Tags: homebrew, puppet, osx-yosemite, unzip

We are in the process of writing a puppet manifest which will install unzip and some other tools in Mac OS X, the puppet manifest looks like below.

```
$packages = ['lsof','unzip','sysstat','telnet', 'git', 'less', 'tree', 'zip']

package {
    $packages:
        ensure => installed,
        provider  => 'brew',
}
```

but when i run this it gives an error as below,

```
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter provider failed on Package[lsof]: Invalid package provider 'brew' at /home/rajeevan/appfactory/modules/wso2base/manifests/packages.pp:9
Wrapped exception:
Invalid package provider 'brew'
Wrapped exception:
Invalid package provider 'brew'
```

Then we executed the command

```
brew install unzip
```

just to ensure the unzip tool is getting installed, but it doesn't.

I have googled it and found a [solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/149080/how-can-i-update-my-version-of-unzip-to-version-6-00-or-higher)

```
$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
$ brew install unzip
```

This works nicely, but as far as puppet concerned, How to do this in my puppet manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search of my own indicated that if you use the [boxen-homebrew](https://github.com/boxen/puppet-homebrew) module, you can write a manifest like this:

```
homebrew::tap { 'homebrew/dupes': }
->
package {
    $packages:
        ensure => installed,
        provider  => 'homebrew',
}
```

Failing that, you could fall back to the `exec` type.

```
exec { 'brew tap homebrew/dupes': ... }
->
package {
   ...
}
```

But it is up to you then to declare fitting queries for the `exec` to determine when it needs running, or whether it is in sync already.